# How does opencv convert RGB to RGBA

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing so work with opencv and I found this: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

Opencv can perform conversion from RGB space to RGBA space, but how does it do it?

As far as I can understand from the text, they just append the grayscale value as the alpha channel, correct?

But that is not really true alpha is it? As far as I can tell, the alpha value is used to describe transparency?

Comment: indeed, this is kind of a "dummy" operation. there is no real transparency information present. transparency is for web designers, not for computer-vision, where it's mostly harmful, even, as the rgb values for a transparent pixel are "undefined"

Comment: I thought so, but I was weirded out by the fact that they have the functionality, so I wanted to know how they were able to extract transparency from rgb color values.

Comment: didnt test it, but probably opencv will add 255 values in the alpha channel during conversion? You can manipulate them and save as a png file to load it in any application that handles alpha channel. But opencv wont magically and automatically add any useful alpha values to your image ;)

Comment: I am torn between deleting the post or keeping it up for others to see if anyone should ever wonder as I did. Do you think this will be useful to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the *grayscale* value is **not** appended. That's not how alpha channels work at all.

**A constant 255 is appended** to form the RGBA tuple, which means **"opaque"**.

`max(ChannelRange)` means 1.0 for `float` type, 255 for `uint8` type, 65535 for `uint16` type.

OpenCV is generally not (yet?) aware of the special meaning of alpha channels, or how to calculate with them. It treats all channels the same.